# Running node (express) on linux produces Error: spawn EACCES

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, express, port

I'm building a node app with using Expressjs and I'm trying to run my node app on a freshly installed Ubuntu (I just installed git and node v 0.10.19).

Sadly though, I'm getting the following error when trying to run the app in terminal:

```
 Events.js:72
    throw er; // unhandled 'error' event

Error: spawn EACCES
```

I'm running on port 3000 and I am using sudo. I also tried as root and I also played around with different ports above the 1024 threshold.

The app is just basic Expressjs and I'm using the default method for opening the app socket:

```
  app.listen(3000);
```

I'm a Linux noob so any help is appreciated. the app works just great on Windows by the way.

The basic server code:

```
    var express = require('express')
    , app = express()
    , fs = require ('fs')
    , lingua = require('lingua');

    process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';

    app.configure(function(){
        app.set('view engine', 'jade');
        app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
        app.setMaxListeners(100);
        app.use(express.bodyParser());
        app.use(express.methodOverride());
        app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
        app.use(express.favicon(__dirname + '/public/core/favicon.ico'));
        app.use(lingua(app, {
            defaultLocale: 'translation_',
            storageKey: 'lang',
            path: __dirname+'/public/translations/',
            cookieOptions: {
                httpOnly: false,        
                expires: new Date(Date.now(-1)),  
                secure: false
            }
        }));
        app.use(app.router);
        app.locals.pretty = true;
    });

    app.configure('development', function(){   
        app.enable('verbose errors');
        app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));  
    });

    app.configure('production', function(){
        app.disable('verbose errors');
        app.use(express.errorHandler()); 
    });   

    require('./lib/routing/routing')(app,{ verbose: !module.parent });


    app.listen(3000);
```

You can test it out yourself by installing: `npm install mediacenterjs`

Comment: does it still happen with `require(http).createServer(app).listen(3000)`

Comment: Testing it now :) One moment please!

Comment: oh sorry i forgot quotes. i can't edit my previous comment anymore but it should read: `require('http').createServer(app).listen(3000)`. you dont need to install http, its built in.

Comment: Thanks but the error remains saldy.

Comment: Damn! My only other guess is that you aren't actually running it as root. Are you doing `sudo node app.js`? Does `sudo touch /etc/foo.test` create a file `/etc/foo.test` without a permissions problem?

Comment: Thanks for your help! Yes, the foo.test get's created just fine. I'm actually testing this as root as well. But sadly the error keeps popping up. if you want to test it out yourself you can install the app with `npm mediacenterjs`. Thanks again :)

Comment: What does `node -v` show?

Comment: I'm running the latest 0.10.19 version. Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I solved it by setting the file permissions correctly.

It works by settings read/write and execute permissions.

```
  sudo chmod -R a+rwx APPNAME/file
```

Comment: Fixed my problem with eaccess error 3 on file writes.  Read worked perfectly but the permissions on the folders up the chain were not correct.

Comment: While this might fix an issue, it also makes APPNAME WRITABLE to everyone, which on servers is a HUGE security risk.

Comment: @gerasalus, you are right, I changed my answer to setting the rights of just the file. Which also worked just fine. Thanks!

Comment: Write permission is not necessary. You only need `chmod a+x /path/to/file`

Comment: giving writable access to anyone even for one file is still security risk

Comment: adding executable permission (+x) solved the issue