# Atom beautify spawn EACCES

Tags: atom-editor

I am trying to install an add-on to clean up my PHP called Atom beautify.

Every time I run the plugin to make my PHP file pretty (Atom Beautify) I get this showing up:

```
Error: spawn EACCES
at exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:313:11)
at exports.spawn (child_process.js:392:9)
at /Users/myusername/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/src/beautifiers/beautifier.coffee:349:13
at Promise._execute (/Users/myusername/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:300:9)
at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/Users/myusername/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:483:18)
at new Promise (/Users/myusername/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:79:10)
at PHPCSFixer.module.exports.Beautifier.spawn (/Users/myusername/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/src/beautifiers/beautifier.coffee:346:16)
at /Users/myusername/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/src/beautifiers/beautifier.coffee:308:10
at tryCatcher (/Users/myusername/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/myusername/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/myusername/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/myusername/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/myusername/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
at Promise._fulfill (/Users/myusername/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:638:18)
at PromiseArray._resolve (/Users/myusername/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise_array.js:126:19)
at PromiseArray._promiseFulfilled (/Users/myusername/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise_array.js:144:14)
at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/myusername/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:574:26)
at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/myusername/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/myusername/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
at Async._drainQueue (/Users/myusername/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
at Async._drainQueues (/Users/myusername/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
at Async.drainQueues (/Users/myusername/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
```

I am currently using a Mac computer if that matters at all.

Comment: I know nothing about Atom - but EACCES error is almost certainly a permission issue. Do a `chown` for your yourself in you work directory and it probably will fix it.

Comment: Hi EdH! Thanks so much for the reply! I am actually not certain on how to do that. Could you give me a little guidance on how to go about doing that? Sorry I'm such a noobie lol. Thanks again Ed!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running node (express) on linux produces Error: spawn EACCES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009778/running-node-express-on-linux-produces-error-spawn-eacces)

Answer (score 1):

Line 349 of [beautifier.coffee](https://github.com/Glavin001/atom-beautify/blob/master/src/beautifiers/beautifier.coffee) is:

```coffee
cmd = spawn(exe, args, options)
```

This is where it would make a call to the beautify program. For PHP, that seems to default to [php-cs-fixer](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer), as shown in [php.coffee](https://github.com/Glavin001/atom-beautify/blob/master/src/languages/php.coffee):

```coffee
defaultBeautifier: "PHP-CS-Fixer"
```

So you probably want to verify that PHP-CS-Fixer is installed and that it is set up properly (the program is readable / executable, preferably in your PATH).

The [PHP-CS-Fixer](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer) README has installation instructions.